# Call Variable php / mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I got the following code:

```
if($allegati_tab) $DIV_ALLEGATI_LINK .= "<a href=\"javascript:;\" onclick=\"openWindow('add.attach.php?t='+tabella_alias+'&amp;id='+localIDRecord,'Allegati',70);\" id=\"href_tab_allegati\">"._("upload/change image")." (0)</a><br />";
```

which creates this link

```
.../vfront/add.attach.php?t=attendees&id=15
```

now i just need to call for the 15 (localIDRecord) here

```
$tabella =($data_tab['table_name']);

$id = I NEED IT HERE;
```

so how do I define the $id as the LocalIDRecord? I just need the number there. (This all happens within the same file so there shouldn't be any need to include anything else)

Here is the complete code segment

```
$tabella =($data_tab['table_name']);

$id = 14;

$qa=$vmsql->query("SELECT * FROM "._TABELLA_ALLEGATO."
            WHERE tipoentita='$tabella'
            AND codiceentita='$id'
            ORDER BY nomefileall, lastdata");


 $matrice_info_allegati=$vmsql->fetch_assoc_all($qa);


for($i=0;$i<count($matrice_info_allegati);$i++){




                    $estensione=substr($matrice_info_allegati[$i]['nomefileall'],-3,3);

        if($estensione=='gif' || $estensione=='jpg' || $estensione=='png' || 
        $estensione=='GIF' || $estensione=='JPG' || $estensione=='PNG'){

            $immagine='<img src="thumb.php?id='.$matrice_info_allegati[$i]['codiceallegato'].'" alt="'.$matrice_info_allegati[$i]['nomefileall'].'" class="thumb" />';
        }
        else{

            $immagine = img_filetype($matrice_info_allegati[$i]['nomefileall']);
        }

        echo "


            <div class=\"allegato-img\">".$immagine."
```

Heres a link for the complete file: http://www.hc-wg.com/code.zip

Answer (score 4):

Simply use [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php):

```
$id = (isset($_GET["id"]) ? intval($_GET["id"]) : false);
var_dump($id);
```

If ID is not specified, the default value will be `false`.

Remember to escape your input if you're using this in MySQL though.

If you're using [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (which you should - **do not use the mysql_* functions!** [See why right here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php)), then you should use prepared statements.

PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

MySQLi: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: If I use that code i geat bool(false), however if I just insert $id = 15 it does what i want. Any ideas why that code won't work? Sorry, I'm a newbie to php/sql.

Comment: @user1826828 We agree that you are inputting this code in add.attach.php, right?

Comment: sorry, my bad, i'm trying to add the code to the file in which the link to add.attach.php is located. Is there any way to do so? Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: If you don't have the parameter in the URL, you can't use `$_GET`. It seems like you try to get a variable from javascript in PHP - you can't do this. PHP is server sided (executed once on page load) and javascript is client sided (runs on the client machine as much as you want it to, throughout the entire visit)

Comment: ah ok, thanks for clarifying. Is there any way to get that value? It's Vfront a Database Frontend. On the page I'm talking about you can watch the entries via a form and switch back and forth between the different entries via buttons. so somehow it calls up the entry id when I push a button right? I just want to also put that entry id as $id or maybe there is a different way? I added the code for the complete segment up top

Comment: @user1826828 I'm afraid you need to clarify - where would you get the `$id` from in your complete code, if you're not getting it from the URL?

Comment: I don't really know ;) however there must be something within the complete file (too big to post i'm afraid) which outputs the mysql entry id right? since i can switch between entries via a forward and back button (there is no change in the visible url up top) is there any other way? That code works btw. i just need the 14 to be dynamic. everything else works fine

Comment: I added a link to the complete file to the original post, maybe that clarifies things

Comment: @user1826828 The *complete file* only includes various `include` and `require_once` calls.

Comment: which included file would you need? I would be more than happy to upload it ;) Thanks again for your help. It's much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $_GET['id']; /*referring to add.attach.php?t=attendees&id=15 */
if(isset($id)) {$id= $id; }
else {$id= ''; }  /*add a default number or leave it blank */

$t = $_GET['t'];
if(isset($t)) {$t= $t; }
else {$t= ''; }  /*add a default number or leave it blank */
```

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure this would come up with a `NOTICE` if the keys don't exist in `$_GET`.

Comment: I would suggest you read the comments below the top-voted answer.  This won't work because the user isn't clicking that link.